# Automatic asterisks for comments in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, comments, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to make the switch from Eclipse CDT to Visual Studio 2019 for C++ development.

In Eclipse, typing `/*` followed by enter create block comments with a space followed by an asterisk on the second line and below, as can be seen below. I would like a way of automatically placing the asterisks after the first line, so I don't have to format all my comments manually every time I add a new line.

If I type the same keys in Visual Studio as I did in Eclipse, the following happens:

What I want to get, and got in Eclipse:

```
/*
 *
 */
```

What I actually get in Visual Studio 2019:

```
/*
*/
```

Is there a tool/extension I need for this, or did I miss an option in Visual Studio to enable this behaviour?

Comment: C++ comment delimiters are not the same as Java comment delimiters...

Comment: @DavidPostill This is true. I have edited my question to more accurately describe what I'm looking for, and removed the context of javadoc-style comments, since c++ indeed doesn't have anything to do with those style of comments. However, the question still stands, since c++ does have `/* ... */` style comments, and the same question applies here.

Comment: Sounds like you need a third-party add-on that maintains the style you want.

Comment: The different is just you've to press one key extra.